# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar una palabra específica en un texto?

Tags: php

¡Hola! Estuve buscando un código en el cual me permita realizar una búsqueda de un archivo de texto a través de PHP. La función que quiero que tenga el código sería que si encuentra la palabra especificada en un GET, me devuelva un true (en caso contrario, un false). Un ejemplo de la URL que utilizaría es: https://example.com/buscador.php.

La lista de palabras que utilizo sería:

> perro
>
> gato
>
> zorro

Al utilizar https://example.com/buscador.php?buscar=perro me devuelve true ya que existe la palabra perro. Pero al utilizar reemplazar perro por "perr" también me devuelve true. Intenté muchos métodos diferentes pero todos me devuelven lo mismo. ¿Creen que mi problema se podría solucionar? ¡Gracias!

**EDIT**: Mi versión de PHP es 7.2.24 y mi código es:

```
<?php

$web = file_get_contents('http://example.com/example.txt');
$buscado = $_GET['buscar'];

if (strpos($web, $buscado) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

Comment: Debes colocar lo que has intentado coloca el código que has usado , para que te puedan ayudar así será mas fácil modificar el código, aumentar o quitar dependiendo el caso.

Comment: Añadí el último código que utilicé pero como dije, intenté muchos tipos de códigos y lamentablemente ninguno me funcionó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la función busca un string dentro de otro

EDIT: usando Word Boundary \b

```
$buscado = "/\b" . $_GET['buscar'] . "\b/";
If (preg_match($buscando, $web, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
  echo true;
} else {
  echo false;
}
```

Info:
https://infoheap.com/php-regex-word-boundary/

Comment: ¡Hola, gracias por contestar! Probé de esa forma y tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: Encontré una forma de php para ponerle límite de palabra y buscar en un arreglo. Prueba a ver qué tal

Comment: ¡Gracias! Me funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Genial!! Todos los días se aprende algo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios detalles con esto que parece tan trivial. La respuesta que te dan de poner los espacios a un lado y otro de la palabra, parece correcta, excepto... cuando no lo es.

Para un cadena `"gato perro gallo"` funcionaría, porque la función `strpos()` encontraría el string `" perro "`, pero con `"perro gato gallo"` no funcionaría porque no hay un espacio antes de perro.

Si lo estás leyendo de un archivo, probablemente lo que te esté llegando sea `"gato\nperro\ngallo"`.

Se me ocurren algunas formas, lo primero es NO buscar contra lo que estás trayendo de la red, sin primero "limpiarlo" un poco, por ejemplo, quitándole los espacios y saltos de línea, y después iterando sobre la lista que te quede.

Otra, que creo que sería la más correcta, sería utilizando expresiones regulares y buscando la palabra (palabra se define como una serie de caracteres con fronteras con el inicio o fin de línea, y/o delimitadores de palabras, como tabs, espacios, cambios de línea, etc.)